# How do I get ONLY the IP address from an nmap result

Tags: linux, sed

How do I strip out an IP address the resultant line from arp which includes the correct MAC address and the IP address the machine is found at with something like 
`arp -a | grep "70:d1" > address_file.txt`

This gives me the following output:
`? (10.0.0.9) at b8:27:eb:3:79:d1 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]`

I've tried various incantations of sed with no luck.  The latest attempt is:

```
cat address_file.txt | sed 's/(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}//p' address_file.txt
```

There is probably something procedurally wrong that I'm doing, but I'm running low on patience as this was supposed to be a quick and dirty hack to provide some automation.  I would also note that I am using a Mac running OS Mojave as I have read that they are some regex differences between BSD sed and other versions of sed.

I should note that I perform a nmap of the subnet because the arp entry can be stale and the machine will no longer be online or a different address but has produced no traffic.

Comment: may be this `grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' address_file.txt` or `grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+' address_file.txt`

Comment: a) P is not an option on mac OS and b) it gives me the line I started with, which is why I'm using sed as I need the line edited down to just the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parenthesis to extract what is inside:

```
arp -a | sed -e s'/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/g'
```